# Undelete request, Question 67384

Tags: support, status-completed, undelete-request

An answer to [Source and context of $\frac{22}{7} - \pi = \int_0^1 (x-x^2)^4 dx/(1+x^2)$?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/67384/source-and-context-of-frac227-pi-int-01-x-x24-dx-1x2) posted on 9 June 2011 gained 31 upvotes before being deleted by its author on 23 August 2012. Would those who can do so please vote to undelete this valuable answer?

Comment: Meanwhile, the link in a comment is outdated. The current version should be http://www.nieuwarchief.nl/serie5/pdf/naw5-2000-01-4-372.pdf

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've undeleted this answer. (And also edited the link in the comment.)

Comment: Thank you!${}{}$

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little confused by what happened.  It looks like perhaps that user simply deleted their account, and all their answers were deleted as a consequence.  Perhaps somebody should just re-post that answer under their own name as a community-wiki answer?

Comment: This is fine as it goes, but I think undeleting the original answer is even better.

Comment: I think it is more appropriate to have someone re-post an essentially equivalent answer.  Presumably the user wanted to delete their account for a reason, we might as well respect that.  I think such actions can help build trust among those suspicious of how we might use their contributions.

Comment: An anonymous user, so no, I do not see that.

Comment: Anyway, once you post on the site, the content is licensed under a Creative Commons Attribute-ShareAlike license, so I am not quite in favor of one-sided deletion that actually decreases the usefulness of the site, or of tip-toeing about it and posting the content again as CW or somesuch. (But I may well be in the minority here, it is not something I plan to argue, in case quid shows up.)

Comment: There's a big gap between doing what is legally required of yourself and in being considerate, nice and/or doing the right thing.  Anyhow I'm not trying to make a big point here either.

Comment: +1 and echoing @RyanBudney's last comment, word for word.

Comment: @Ryan: No, the user deleted their content before deleting their account.

Comment: We've been through this, very recently. At the time, I re-posted an exactly equivalent answer (I simply did a cut'n'paste), and was advised by a moderator that it was better to vote for undeletion if I had that privilege, otherwise start a thread here on meta. See http://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/665/undelete-request-question-23943

Comment: To avoid a potential misconception, I will add that the post was deleted about **a year** before the account was deleted. Deletion of this post and of the account seem unrelated.